# Trying to catch exception in order to see request (HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException)

Tags: spring, exception, request, servlet-filters

I am trying to catch an exception in order to `evaluate` and see which `request` from the front-end caused it. However, my breakpoint is never triggered:

```
 try{
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        }catch(Exception e){
            if(e instanceof org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException)
                throw new HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException(e.getMessage());

            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
```

Any reason why my breakpoint inside the catch statement is never executed? The stacktrace denotes this specific method as the source of the exception.

Comment: where is your break point?

Comment: Breakpoint is @ `if(e instanceof`

Comment: Because the `DispatcherServlet` itself is handling the exception. From the perspective of the filter there is no exception...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was provided by @M. Deinum :

> Because the DispatcherServlet itself is handling the exception. From
>   the perspective of the filter there is no exception.